# Amazon S3 (S3FS) Owncloud permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, owncloud, s3fs

I got my bucket mounted and everythings works fine. My Fstab is like this

```
mybucket /path/to/mountpoint fuse.s3fs _netdev,allow_other 0 0
```

But when i hit the Owncloud homepage it tells me i have to set the chmod 0770 to the directory. But the S3fs mount can't be chmodded at all.

Removing the allow_other is not either working, because only root has access to the mount.

Answer (score 3):

Well 10 months passed after you posted your issue, but I just found myself in the same situation, here is the solution for someone who needs it:

On the `/etc/fstab` file just add the auto-mount entry:

```
s3fs#YOUR_S3_BUCKET_NAME /YOUR_MOUNTPOINT fuse allow_other,use_cache=/tmp/cache,uid=apache,gid=apache,umask=007 0 0
```

In the case above it is mounting it with the ownership of `apache` user and group. `umask=007` does the trick and set the permissions on the folder that you need.